# Create infinite loop with moving divs using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, settimeout, setinterval

I need to simulate a band that moves from left to right continuously, carrying 15 divs on it and moving them in a circle, like a carousel. When they reach the right margin to appear from the left.

I have the code that works for 1 div(more or less), but Im having troubles making the loop that includes all 15 divs.

What am I missing?

Here's what I have so far:

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="fooObject0">1</div>
<div id="fooObject1">2</div>
....
<div id="fooObject13">14</div>
<div id="fooObject14">15</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
font:76% normal verdana,arial,tahoma;
width:600px;
height:600px;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
border:1px solid;
}

div {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:8em;
width:55px;
height:70px;
line-height:3em;
background:#99ccff;
border:1px solid #003366;
white-space:nowrap;
padding:0.5em;
}
```

javascript

```
var foo = null; // object


function doMove(id) {

    foo = document.getElementById(id);

    foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';
    setTimeout(doMove(id),20); // call doMove in 20msec

    if(foo.style.left == "600px") {
        foo.style.left = 0;
    }

}

function init() {

    for(i=0;i<15;i++){
        var foo = document.getElementById('fooObject' + i); // get the "foo" object
          foo.style.left = -i*55+'px'; // set its initial position to 0px
          doMove('fooObject' + i); // start animating
          console.log('fooObject' + i);
      }

}


window.onload = init;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: One note is that you don't want the div to appear at position 0 but instead at position negative "width of the div" px.  In other words, you want the right edge of that div to be right off the left side so that it'll rotate in.  Check out http://jsfiddle.net/ where you can put these together and easily test and revise, as well as share it here for others to help.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tyj54pu4/5/ - I have no idea why the last div is too wide.

Comment: Removing the padding fixes the width issue for the last div.

Comment: I recommend that you use jQuery along with this, particularly the "animate" functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It call an invalid function `setTimeout(doMove(id), 20);`.

`doMove(id)` return `undefined`, or you use "shared var" (Orientad Object) or `doMove` need return other `function`.

Note: `var foo = null; // object` this variable causes conflict when using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`

Try this (read my comments in code):

```
function doMove(id) {
    return function() {
        var foo = document.getElementById(id);//Global variable causes conflict when using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`

        foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';
        setTimeout(doMove(id),20); //setTimeout need an valid function

        if(foo.style.left == "600px") {
            foo.style.left = 0;
        }
    }
}

function init() {

    for(i=0;i<15;i++){
        var foo = document.getElementById('fooObject' + i);
          foo.style.left = -i*55+'px';
          doMove('fooObject' + i)(); //doMove need "()", because not run "direct"
          console.log('fooObject' + i);
      }

}
```

I modified the code for effect "carousel" and fix the problem with "left" (In 1 to 5 div):

```
function carrousel() {
    var numberOfItems = 15; //Change this if needed
    var delay = 1; //Change delay time if needed
    var limitArea = 599; //Size limit your carousel area (600px, used 599 for limit with `>`)
    var sizeObject = 58; //Width size of objects

    //Don't change
    var index = 0; //Current index
    var allItems = []; //Indexed objects

    //Get and index all objects
    for(index = 0; index < numberOfItems; index++){//user var
        allItems[index] = document.getElementById("fooObject" + index);
    }

    //Convert position left for int and detect "NaN"
    var getPosition = function(pos) {
        pos = parseInt(pos);

        if (isNaN(pos)) {
            return parseInt(-(index * sizeObject));
        } else {
            return parseInt(pos + 1);
        }
    };

    var doMoveAll = function() {
        var foo, post;

        for(index = 0; index < numberOfItems; index++){//user var
            foo = allItems[index];//Current object

            pos = getPosition(foo.style.left);//Get position

            //Detect if object are in out area
            if(pos > limitArea) {
                var beforeItem;

                //Get before object for effect carousel
                switch(index + 1) {
                    case 1:
                        beforeItem = "fooObject" + (numberOfItems - 1);
                    break;
                    default:
                        beforeItem = "fooObject" + (index - 1);
                }

                //Get position again, but used before object
                pos = (
                    getPosition(document.getElementById(beforeItem).style.left) - sizeObject
                );
                foo.style.left = pos + "px";
            } else {
                foo.style.left = pos + "px";
            }
        }

        //Timeout delay
        window.setTimeout(doMoveAll, delay);
    };
    doMoveAll();//Init
};
window.onload = carrousel;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It's working now, besides a small issue. After a complete circle, after div 15 it jumps to div 5 instead of div 1. Any idea why?

Comment: @mary1, all items before "5" gets incorret position, replace `background:#99ccff;` by `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);` for detect the issue. I will tried detect the problem in your code, please wait

Comment: Yes, divs from 1 to 5 overlap the divs from 10 to 15 because of this condition I put: if(foo.style.left == "600px") {foo.style.left = 0;}. I added this condition because I want to create the carousel effect, like when they reach margin-right to disappear and appear later from the left like in a carousel.

Comment: @mary1 I modified your code for try solve the problem with objects before "5" (1 to 5), try please.